# Selenium in docker cannot access local network

Tags: c#, docker, selenium-webdriver

I have issue to connect to website on my local network with selenium docker. I can do it with selenium on local PC.

I have my own DNS server on 192.168.1.132 and I want to scrape website on 192.168.1.1 from docker on localhost. Whenever I try it, c# code ends with exception on driver.Navigate()

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/7ef05b4b64ea31e8d0e377c1cb833036/url timed out after 60 seconds.'

Code:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new();
        options.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
        options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");


        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(configuration.IpToSearch); //IpToSearch = http://192.168.1.1 (NOK) http://google.com (OK)
            var login = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("password-text")));
            login.SendKeys(configuration.Password);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

Container setup:

> docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --dns=192.168.1.132 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome

Containers are running in docker desktop v24.0.6 on windows 11

Container log:

```
2023-11-13 07:53:30 06:53:30.673 INFO [LocalNode.newSession] - Session created by the Node. Id: 7503932bc446870745db8cf625604178, Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 119.0.6045.123, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 119.0.6045.105 (38c72552c5e..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:46267}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://172.17.0.2:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 119.0.6045.123, se:vnc: ws://172.17.0.2:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.17.0.2:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
2023-11-13 07:53:30 06:53:30.691 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session created by the Distributor. Id: 7503932bc446870745db8cf625604178 
2023-11-13 07:53:30  Caps: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 119.0.6045.123, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 119.0.6045.105 (38c72552c5e..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:46267}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://172.17.0.2:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 119.0.6045.123, se:vnc: ws://172.17.0.2:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://172.17.0.2:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
2023-11-13 07:58:33 06:58:33.421 WARN [SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute] - Unable to execute request: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2023-11-13 07:58:33 Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
2023-11-13 07:58:33 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
2023-11-13 07:58:33 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
2023-11-13 07:58:33 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2023-11-13 07:58:33 Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
2023-11-13 07:58:33 System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
2023-11-13 07:58:33 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
2023-11-13 07:58:33     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute0(JdkHttpClient.java:410)
```

Thanks for all your help

Comment: you need to add a bridge network adapter to your docker instance, so you can access the network outside of your docker instance's network

Comment: @Dean Van Greunen It does not seems to be doing what I expected. I have created network. Attached simple alpine container to it and tried to ping from container to 192.168.1.1 and it timed out. When I try to ping google.com it works. So nothing changed